# How to convert Damped Track and Follow Path of camera into Frames?

Tags: animation, constraints, path

I have set up a path my camera should follow, and an Object it should track with Damped Track.
Now, what I wanna do is, make the camera movement into frames because I want to have a fluent movement where it tracks the moving Object, but then, when the Object passes I want to have a different angle and the cconstraint not to follow the Object anymore. And I want to edit the velocity of the camera-movement along the path for certain segments..

The Only and easyest way I know how to do this, (because follow path is really pretty dumm set up, cuz I couldnt' find a velocity modifier or something...) is with individual frames.

So how can I convert these two things into frames?

Comment: I have tried to bake but this doesn't work, for when I delete the path, the camera goes to oblivion..

Answer (score 1):

When you Bake Action, be sure to enable the Visual Keying checkbox. This ensures that the 'final' state of the object is captured, after all transforms, constraints, etc. have been applied.

[image: Bake Action]

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it was alot harder than I think but I managed to do it.
I found out that you can rightclick on the options like "path animation" or "frames" down in the properties and insert frames, you can then animate the influence or framerates in the nla-editor. So to clear the constraint you just set the influence to zero on the frame you want.
The whole process allowed me to keep the path constraint, without converting to frames, which didn't work in the first place.